# Can I use Laptop with one WiFi and one Ethernet Port interface to setup firewall - OPNSense?

Tags: firewall, wifi, local-area-network, opnsense

I am trying to setup OPNsense Firewall at my residence using a spare laptop which has one WiFI and one Ethernet interface. I was able to install OPNsense and configure the interfaces to LAN and WAN. The problem is If I select WiFi interface for LAN then I am not able to connect my other systems to this firewall. Vise-versa I am not able to connect it to the IPS router via WiFi interface as I don't see options to scan networks and connect to WiFi on OPNsense. Is it mandatory for the system on which the firewall runs to have 2 Ethernet (cable) Ports ?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/interfaces.html

> Most interfaces **have to be assigned to a physical port**. By default, LAN is assigned to port 0 and WAN is assigned to port 1. Assignments can be changed by going to Interfaces ‣ Assignments. This lists existing interfaces, with the interface name on the left and the physical port selected in the dropdown. New ones can be created here as well, using a non-occupied physical port.

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/other-interfaces.html

> Besides wired, wireless and VPN interfaces, there are also some other, virtual interfaces...

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/firewall_vip.html

> When using additional addresses for features like NAT or binding services to different interfaces, you can add extra addresses to already defined interfaces using Virtual IPs.

Implied in that is: by default opnsense expects that your logical network layout matches the physical ports in the device running opnsense, but you can use logical/virtual devices. That is common when you for example make use of VLAN tags for logical network segregation, VPN interconnects and/or Virtual IP-addresses for NAT.
Since opnsense can't autodetect and assign virtual interfaces you will first need to create them and then manually configure your setup accordingly.